# Changing Key exchange method in SSH.NET

Tags: .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

The webpage (https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/) says it supports several Key Exchange Methods:

> SSH.NET supports the following key exchange methods:
>
> - diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
> - diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
> - diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
> - diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

But there is absolutely no documentation on how to use one of these, DH_GROUP_EXCHANGE_SHA256, for example.

Has anyone done this?  Can you give me some direction here?

Thanks. Aaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConnectionInfo` has `KeyExchangeAlgorithms`, which defines list of algorithms the SSH.NET will offer to the server.

The client and the server should pick the best algorithm supported by both sides. But it seems to me that, as `Dictionary` does not have a deterministic order, SSH.NET might not honor the order.

Though in general, if "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256" is not picked, I'd rather suspect the server not to support it.

Comment: Okay, good to know.  It's actually listed as the first item in the dictionary.