# c# SSH connect to Console Server - No suitable authentication method

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I am trying to connect to a Avocent ACS6000 with **SSH using c#** WinForms. The follow code is successful when trying to connect to a **Windows SSH Server**.

But it does not work on the desired device throws **exception**

`exception : No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication (publickey,keyboard-interactive)`

I've found the following solutions but either not match for my problem or I don't know how to use them.

- [Changing Key exchange method in SSH.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722700/changing-key-exchange-method-in-ssh-net) ( don't know how to pick and use a key )
- [SSH.NET Public Key Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344409/ssh-net-public-key-authentication) or [SSH.NET Authenticate via private key only (public key authentication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667142/ssh-net-authenticate-via-private-key-only-public-key-authentication) (can't make it work)

**IS IT POSSIBLE** to force windows to include the `hmac-sha2-512` argument by default. So when I try to connect it will always use this algorithm ? Using Putty it prompts me to accept the key and it works perfect.

(code using using Renci.SshNet)

```
sshclient = new SshClient(IPadress, port,  username, password);
try
{
    OutputRichTextBox.AppendText("SSH Conecting..." + Environment.NewLine);
    sshclient.Connect();
    if (sshclient.IsConnected == true)
    {
        OutputRichTextBox.AppendText("Connected to Server" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    else
    {
        OutputRichTextBox.AppendText("Ping failed." + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
catch
{
    OutputRichTextBox.AppendText("Error : Not Connected" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

I first **tested it to the Windows Server** CommandPrompt using the `ssh root@x.x.x.x` and it connects successfully. But to **the Avocent** device it **requires** to `ssh root@x.x.x.x -m hmac-sha2-512` command

When **trying to connect without the last argument** with CMD:

```
C:\Users\User>ssh root@x.x.x.x
The authenticity of host 'x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:(**key**).
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?

Corrupted MAC on input.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 10.1.10.47 port 22: message authentication code incorrect
```

Comment: The equivalent of OpenSSH `-m` in SSH.NET is `ConnectionInfo.HmacAlgorithms`. Though I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by *"force windows"*? How can it be that the device *"requires .... `-m hmac-sha2-512`*? It rather looks like the device is buggy.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The device is not buggy. I've tested more windows clients ( that prompts the same error ) and a macOS client that does not prompt the same error. So I think its a matter of configuration of the SSH Client. So, I thought if there is a configuration of the openSSH client in windows that can include this argument by default.
Thank you for your answer, I will try it

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I can't figure out how to set HmacAlgorithm

Comment: 1) That MacOS client works does not show that the device is not buggy. You should not need to explicitly select algorithm to use. The client and the server should pick an algo both support. If they pick algo that does not work, it likely means one side has the algo implemented incorrectly. I find it way more likely it's the device-side, rather then OpenSSH. 2) I assume you need to `.Remove` all algos from `HmacAlgorithm` except for `hmac-sha2-512`. 3) Though were HMAC the actual issue, I do not think your SSH.NET connection would get as far as to failing an authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this to your ssh config file (C:\Users\<username>\.ssh):

```
Host <your_host_ip>
    MACs hmac-sha2-512
```

p.s. If you do not have config file, create it.